# Interpolate string in Rust with symbols other then braces

Tags: rust

I want to inline EdgeQL queries in Rust, but there are a many braces inside.
I want to avoid escaping `{{ }}` in `format!` every time.

Is it possible to change braces to different symbols for inserting values, e.g. `%` or JS-like `${}`, preferably at compile-time?

Comment: Maybe this can help: https://github.com/FlorianNAdam/ext_format-rs

Comment: Pretty sure you never, ever want to interpolate variables into a sql query. Either the query should be a string literal or a sql interpolation library should be used.

Comment: @BallpointBen there are shapes, not variables. Shapes are const/static strings.

Answer (score 1):

No, unless you're willing to write your own macro, you can't change the string interpolation syntax. But you could pass the respective strings as arugments as well:

```rust
println!("{}{}", "string with unescaped braces {} ", 123);
```

prints:

```
string with unescaped braces {} 123
```

Of course when you mix text with braces that quickly becomes more cumbersome than just using `{{`/`}}` directly.